# Поиск в bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Может кто то делал поиск по таблице по данным из формы, на подобии фильтров которые в полях столбцов, только вынесенные в отдельную форму. Поделитесь примером. Или  хотя бы какое свойство копать. 
Так как здесь реализован поиск http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/toolbar.html

```
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                data: data,
                pagination: true,
                search: true,
                pageSize: 25
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, нужно добавить параметр `data-search` в `<table>`. По умолчанию поиск идет по всем колонкам из таблицы, чтобы исключить колонку  нужно добавить аттрибут `data-searchable="false"` в `<th>`, которая будет участвовать в поиске. Подробнее и примеры есть тут, если еще не видел: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Comment: вот у меня есть в форме дата from -> to сейчас сижу ковыряю как этот фильтр присобачить. Остальное сделал через filterColumnsPartial